# C# - TcpClient just receive the first packet

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I'm developing a c# program just to get some knowledge about TcpClient. So, this program receives a message from another and sends back a OK packet to it, confirming the established connection.

On the first request, it works pretty well, sending back the OK packet without any issues. But on second request, it simply does not reply. Looks like it never received the packet from the client. I can see using a packet sniffer that the packet is being sent from client, but my server has no action.

It's actually printing all requests on console, so I can see if something "went" to the readstream or not. If I close the server or the client, and reopen to stablish a new connection, I receive again the first packet, but not the second.

I've been searching for a solution, at least a week. Many functions simply did not worked for me and I don't want the application to disconnect and reconnect a lot of times.

My server code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int InternalLoop = 0;
    bool Finished = false;
    TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 10000);
    int requestCount = 0;
    TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
    serverSocket.Start();
    while (true)
    {
        bool LoopReceive = true;
        bool LoopSend = false;

        Console.WriteLine(" :::: SERVER STARTED OK");
        clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
        Console.WriteLine(" :::: CONNECTED TO CLIENT");
        requestCount = 0;
        NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();

        string Packettosend = "";

        while (LoopReceive == true)
        {
            try
            {
                //Gets the Client Packet
                requestCount = requestCount + 1;
                byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[128];
                networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, bytesFrom.Length);
                string dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);

                Packettosend = "ALIVE";
                Console.WriteLine(" ::: SENDING ALIVE PACKET");
                LoopReceive = false;
                LoopSend = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        while (LoopSend == true || InternalLoop < 2)
        {
            try
            {
                InternalLoop += 1;
                if (Packettosend == "ALIVE")
                {
                    Byte[] sendBytes1 = { 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01 };
                    networkStream.Write(sendBytes1, 0, sendBytes1.Length);
                    networkStream.Flush();

                    LoopReceive = true;
                    LoopSend = false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no packet on the level you are on, only streams. Pretend you are writing the data to a disk, copying the file to the other computer and reading it. How can you tell how much he fist computer wrote in the first Write call?

Comment: The return value of `Read` is crucial. It's the only way to know how much data you've actually got in the buffer. And why those two loops? You only ever write in response to a read, you only need one loop.

Comment: Luaan, thanks for the tip about double loop. I fixed that and looks OK.

Comment: Luaan, thanks for the tip about double loop. I fixed that and looks OK. About return of Read, what do you mean? I'm really starting with Tcp and didn't get what you mean.

Comment: with `AcceptTcpClient` you wait for a _new_ client to connect. do this only _outside_ the outer loop.  btw `while (x==true)` is the same as `while (x)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you don't receive the second packet is this line:

```
clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
```

This call waits for a *new* client to connect to your server's listener socket.

Move this line outside your outer loop to accept only one client and use only that single `clientSocket` in your loops.

(I'd like to add details but am on the road and it's hard to type all that on a phone...)

Comment: René, I made the changes you said, and worked well. But now I'm thinking  how to deal with more than one connection at same time in this way. I mean, in case of 2 clients connected to my server. Is it possible to handle both without disconnect one of them to reply the other?

Comment: @MarkJohansen yes it is, but that question is a little too broad to answer in a comment. Stack overflow is a Q&A site, so if you have a new (and preferably _specific_) question, please open a new question.

Comment: René, the solution you gave me worked. I made some searches to figure out how to have multiple clients into same server and it's pretty well now.

Thanks for your supporting and I'd wish you a happy new year ;)